# Software/Tool to convert pdf

Tags: pdf, document-converter, file-converter

Looking for Software/Tool to convert normal/traditional/sequential pdf to Booklet PDF and Vice Versa

Comment: What is a "booklet" PDF? Perhaps if you gave specific input, and clearer explanation of the desired output (files and screenshots) you might get an answer.

Comment: Pages with 1,2,3,4...is normal pdf...Booklet PDF will have last page and first page, second last page and second page..goes on..so we will print the pages and put a binding clip in the center and make it as a book